# Invalid left-hand side in assignment on javascript code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why is that so?
The error pointing at third line and I've no idea what's wrong.

```
var app = angular.module('Todolist', []);

app.controller('TasksCtrl') = [
  '$scope', 'Task', function($scope, Task) {
    $scope.tasks = Task.query({
      status: 'incompleted'
    });

   $scope.completed_tasks = Task.query({
     status: 'completed'
    });
  }
];
```

Comment: `app.controller('TasksCtrl')` is a function call expression, and that doesn't make sense on the left side of the `=` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Pointy's comment above, and then take a look at these corrections below.

```
var app = angular.module('Todolist', []);

app.controller('TasksCtrl', ['$scope', 'Task', function($scope, Task) {
    $scope.tasks = Task.query({
      status: 'incompleted'
    });

   $scope.completed_tasks = Task.query({
     status: 'completed'
    });
}]);
```

app.controller is a function, and essentially what you were trying to do is assign a function call a value. You put `method_name() = value` as the expression which is invalid.

In AngularJS, the [.controller()](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) method takes specific arguments for initialization. See the documentation for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign an `array` to a function call expressin. That will never work. If you wan't to define a controller in your angular app, the correct way would be as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('Todolist', []);
app.controller('TasksCtrl', ['$scope', 'Task', function($scope, Task) {
    $scope.tasks = Task.query({
      status: 'incompleted'
    });

   $scope.completed_tasks = Task.query({
     status: 'completed'
    });
  }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks you, taxicala!

Comment: No Problem, glad to help.